# How to authenticate Python flask APIs using Azure active directory

Tags: python, azure

I have created python flask api which I need to authenticate using azure active directory. I have the `client secret`, `client id` and `tenant`. I am following this [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-python-webapp-graphapi/) from Microsoft. But it throws error:

```
Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS65005: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the 
following: The client has not listed any permissions for 'Microsoft Graph' in 
the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, The 
admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check the application identifier in 
the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. 
Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the 
tenant. Client app ID: 561b7942-251c-4f36-8f80-4409947bf61f
```

Can anyone please suggest me good working example/tutorial for authenticating python flask based application using azure active directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code is pointing towards missing permissions.

The example you're following looks good. Please review if you did this step correctly

> 10. Configure Permissions for your application. In the Settings menu, choose the 'Required permissions' section and then, click on Add, then
>       Select an API, and type Microsoft Graph in the textbox. Then, click on
>       Select Permissions and underneath Delegated Permissions select Sign in
>       and read user profile.

I'm giving screenshots to make it more explicit. **Please do follow till the end. Especially the last step of hitting "Grant Permissions". I've seen it get missed many times and resulting in an error like yours, because consent is missing.**

1. Go to edit app settings

[image]

2. Choose Required Permissions

[image]

3. Add Microsoft Graph

[image]

4. **Make sure you select this permission under "Delegated Permissions" section**
   [image]
5. Once you did the "Select" and "Done" to choose selected permissions, this is the step I guess you missed in first time setup. Click on "Grant Permissions"
   [image]

Comment: Thankyou for detailed answer. I will check and update.

Comment: I am facing issues  with portal side of things and azure ad. I will try it asap

Comment: Hello, are you still having issues? I struggled with Python and Azure AD for a while before finally getting it to work, so if you need help, let me know.

Comment: @Emac can you share what are the steps that you did to make it work ?